# How to use entity_reference programatically

Tags: entities

i'm building a module with an Company entity, this entity should be linked to other 2 entities and i think that the type "entity_reference" should be useful for this pourpose, but i dont see how configure this, and only found tutorials to make this by UI, some know how should use or known some link where is weel explained?

There is my actual code, "producto" and "tipo" should be "entity_reference"

```
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
        $fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
            ->setLabel(t('ID'))
            ->setDescription(t('Identificador de la empresa.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

        $fields['uuid'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uuid')
            ->setLabel(t('UUID'))
            ->setDescription(t('Identificador único de la empresa.'))
            ->setReadOnly(TRUE);

        $fields['razon_social'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t("Nombre de la empresa"))
            ->setDescription(t('Nombre de la empresa.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'max_length' => 255,
                'text_processing' => 0,
            ))
            ->setRequired(TRUE);

        $fields['logo'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('uri')
            ->setLabel(t('Logo'))
            ->setDescription(t('Logo de la empresa.'))
            ->addPropertyConstraints('value', ['Image' => []])
            ->setRequired(TRUE);

        $fields['resumen'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t('Descripción de la empresa'))
            ->setDescription(t('Un resumen general de la empresa hacia el mercado.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'default_value' => '',
                'max_length' => 5000,
                'text_processing' => 1,
            ));

        $fields['url'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t("URL"))
            ->setDescription(t('Sitio web de la empresa.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'default_value' => '',
                'max_length' => 255,
                'text_processing' => 0,
            ))
            ->addPropertyConstraints('value', ['Url' => []]);

        $fields['quienes_somos'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t('Quienes Somos'))
            ->setDescription(t('Texto del Quienes Somos.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'default_value' => '',
                'max_length' => 5000,
                'text_processing' => 1,
            ));

        $fields['mision'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t('Misión'))
            ->setDescription(t('Misión de la empresa.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'default_value' => '',
                'max_length' => 5000,
                'text_processing' => 1,
            ));

        $fields['vision'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t('Visión'))
            ->setDescription(t('Visión de la empresa.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'default_value' => '',
                'max_length' => 5000,
                'text_processing' => 1,
            ));

        $fields['tipo'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t('Descripción de la empresa'))
            ->setDescription(t('Un resumen general de la empresa hacia el mercado.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'default_value' => '',
                'max_length' => 5000,
                'text_processing' => 1,
            ));

        $fields['producto'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
            ->setLabel(t('Descripción de la empresa'))
            ->setDescription(t('Un resumen general de la empresa hacia el mercado.'))
            ->setSettings(array(
                'default_value' => '',
                'max_length' => 255,
                'text_processing' => 1,
            ));

        return $fields;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add entity_reference try something like, the following example to reference to user:
Adapted it to your use case.

```
$fields['user_id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Authored by'))
      ->setDescription(t('The user ID of author of Entity entity.'))
      ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
     // Set your target type here change user by your target.
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'user')
      ->setSetting('handler', 'default')
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight' => 5,
        'settings' => [
          'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
          'size' => '60',
          'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
          'placeholder' => '',
        ],
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE);
```

Comment: Is just the example that i need! :D I love you hehehehe, is possible with the same code link others entities created by me by the same way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are welcome, i'm glad that help, yeah of course you can just change the `target_type` to your target_type, it will works.